# How to copy data saved as saveRDS from one project to another one

Tags: r

Due to my study, I have generated several objectives. I would like to copy my data (I saved them using `saveRDS`) from one project to another one.

Is this possible, or not? For example, is there a way similar to export/import dataset?

Comment: SaveRDS is not project dependent but you're saving by default in your working directory, so just give the full path to readRDS

Comment: If you save your data as `saveRDS` then you can use `readRDS` with a full path of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the generated dataFrames or data in a file with `.rdata` extensions with `save` option. For example

```
D1 <- data.table(l = "a", x = 0)
save(file = "./D1.rdata")
```

Form other files you can use

```
load(file = "~/D1.rdata")
D1#verify the data
```